# Присвоить значение переменой

Tags: c#

Есть код:

```
string r1 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//dl[@class='userLink']/dt/textarea").InnerHtml;          
if (r1.Contains("href"))
{ 
    LogSystem.ShowLogMessage("ок");

}
else
{
    LogSystem.ShowLogMessage("не ок");

}
```

Переменная r1 берет значение с сайта, как правило, оно содержит href, но бывают случаи, когда значение неправильное и его нужно обработать.

Сообствено вопрос: допустим, в переменную попало значение `http://site.ru`, как сделать так, чтобы оно обрабатывалось до такого вида `<a href="http://site.ru">http://site.ru</a>`? То есть как обработать эту переменую и задать ей новый вид?

Этот код я  хочу вставить после  `LogSystem.ShowLogMessage("не ок");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так?

```
r1 = String.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{0}</a>", r1);
```